# heroku info でYou do not have access to the app hogeと出てしまう。

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket

heroku infoをしようとすると、下記のエラーがでてしまいます。

```
PS G:\マイドライブ\LocalRepository\firstdash> heroku info
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.60.2.
 !    You do not have access to the app hoge.
PS G:\マイドライブ\LocalRepository\firstdash>
```

この「hoge」は以前によくわからず試しにインストールしたBitbucketで作ったものだと思います。
下記コマンドをすると添付の画像が出てきます。

```
PS G:\マイドライブ\LocalRepository\firstdash> git push -u origin main
```

bitbucketはしばらく使う予定はないので、一旦アンインストールしようともしてみたのですが、アンインストールの方法もよくわからず途方に暮れています。
bitbucketのアンインストールか、heroku infoなどのコマンドが使えるような解決の方向性だけでも教えていただけないでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 下記方法で解決しました！
`git config --global -l`で見たところ。
`remote.origin.url=https://hoge@bitbucket.org/hoge/hoge.git`
`remote.heroku.url=https://git.heroku.com/hoge.git'`
ということで、デフォルト値みたいな形になっているようなので、これをリセットする方法が下記にありました。[参照サイト](https://qiita.com/hijion/items/ae2cccebf5d28ff733f3)
`git config --global --unset remote.origin.url `
`git config --global --unset remote.heroku.url `
とすると解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket はホスティングサービスなので、アンインストールという操作はあり得ません。
使わないのであればそのまま放っておくか、`git push` の後に表示された画面でログイン後にアカウントの削除を行う事になると思います。

"以前によくわからず作成した" リポジトリで `heroku info` を行う必要があるのかも改めて検討し直してください。(新規に作成したリポジトリで実行すればいいだけのような気がします)